# get cheap price with min() from array

Tags: php, arrays, min

Im using min() to get the cheapest price out of an array but its showing the expensive one instead of the cheap one. i also need to get all the data from the cheap price array.

**code**

```
 $dumpData = array();

  if ( !empty($dumpData) && is_array($dumpData) ) {

    $minPriceArray = min($dumpData['data']);

    $price = $func->convert_amount($minPriceArray['currency'],   get_currency(), $minPriceArray['price']);
    echo '<span class="price"><small>From</small> '.$price.' '.get_currency().'</span>';

  }else{
    echo '<span class="price">No data found</span>';
  }
```

**array**

```
 array(4) {
   [0]=>
   array(8) {
     ["logo"]=>
     ["price"]=>
     int(649)
     ["currency"]=>
     string(3) ""
     ["availability"]=>
     string(7) "instock"
   },
   [1]=>
   array(8) {
     ["logo"]=>
     ["price"]=>
     int(849)
     ["currency"]=>
     string(3) ""
     ["availability"]=>
     string(7) "instock"
   },
   [2]=>
   array(8) {
   ...
   },
   [3]=>
   array(8) {
   ...
   }

 }
```

Comment: Are you implementing `min()` to this whole array (with sub arrays)?

Comment: $min = min(array_column($array, 'price'));

Comment: perhaps worth noting that `array_column` is available only after version 5.5. Confused by the code snippet above - initially declaring `$dumpData = array();` and then checking `if ( !empty($dumpData) && is_array($dumpData) ) {` ???

Comment: RramRaider, the data from DB is array or a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function find_min_price_array($arr) {
    $prices = array_column($arr, 'price');
    $min_price = min($prices);

    $min_price_array = array();

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if($value['price'] == $min_price) {
            $min_price_array[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $min_price_array;
}

var_dump(find_min_price_array($arr));
```

The user-defined function `find_min_price_array` returns the array which contains the minimum price. It also returns the arrays which contain same minimum price.

`array_column` returns all the values of a column in the multi-dimensional array. `array_column($arr, 'price')` gets you all the prices in the arrays and then you can find the minimum value easily with `min` function. Then, you can check the minimum price against the price of each array in the multi-dimensional array in the loop.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Anant No problem at all. Your code works perfectly. What the extra thing he needs is to get the array which contains minimum price. He doesn't only want the minimum price to be extracted and also the associated array with the price.